# Whats is Foreward and Inverse mapping in CoreData integration in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, ios6

I am a novice in core data integration and want to know what is foreword mapping and inverse mapping in iOS.

I need to incorporate JSON requests using inverse mapping

please also provide a quick link for the theories if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward mapping means standard referencing of an object within a data object that contains it. Inverse mapping is the other, non-trivial reference back to the containing object.

As always, one of the best tutorials is available via Ray Wenderlich:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: See my link - where they demonstrate the relationship between FailedBankDetails and FailedBankInfo